# VScode can't find packages installed in an environment

Tags: python-3.x, conda, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run some python code on VScode with Code Runer. I'm using a conda environment *ENV*.

The problem I am having is that vscode won't load the packages I have installed in my environment.

The solution that works for most people is making sure that they use the correct python interpreter. I already did that, my interpreter path looks like this:      `/opt/anaconda3/envs/ENV/bin/python`

Even the integrated terminal activates my environment automatically, this is what I see in the vs code terminal:

```
$ source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
$ conda activate ENV
```

I can successfully run the code in this terminal but I can't use the play button in the top right part of the window, it gives me the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'` in the output

I am a beginner here, I hope I gave useful information about my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the package you need `module_name`...into the environment? `conda install module_name`. Then ensure the package needed is in the packages from `conda list`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also very new, but I think I've found something.
In my case, within the env. the python interpreter was actually a link to the base folder interpreter.
So, I've installed the packages I needed in the base Anaconda env. (used the terminal from the environments area within the navigator to pip install them) and voila - when I worked in my env in VS it used the package nicely.